# Why is Facebook JS SDK attempting to connect to z-m-graph.facebook.com

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, content-security-policy

My client side application uses the [Facebook SDK for JavaScript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) loaded directly from the [officially-documented URL (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart) and specifies `v2.9` as the `version` during [initialization](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.9).

The init snippet looks like this:

```
FB.init({
  appId: '[redacted]',
  cookie: true,
  xfbml: false,
  version: 'v2.9'
})
```

The [Graph API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api) reference `graph.facebook.com` in *all* example HTTP request snippets and [make no reference to `z-m-graph.facebook.com`](https://developers.facebook.com/search/?q=z-m-graph.facebook.com); however, I have begun *observing* requests to [`https://z-m-graph.facebook.com/v2.9/`](https://z-m-graph.facebook.com/v2.9/).

It appears that endpoints are pre-configured in the [`sdk.js` script](https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js); here's a snippet I found in `sdk.js` while searching for "z-m-graph" under the `Sources` tab in Chrome dev tools:

```
__d("UrlMapConfig", [], {
  "www": "www.facebook.com",
  "m": "m.facebook.com",
  "connect": "connect.facebook.net",
  "business": "business.facebook.com",
  "api_https": "z-m-api.facebook.com",
  "api_read_https": "z-m-api.facebook.com",
  "graph_https": "z-m-graph.facebook.com",
  "an_https": "an.facebook.com",
  "fbcdn_http": "z-m-static.xx.fbcdn.net",
  "fbcdn_https": "z-m-static.xx.fbcdn.net",
  "cdn_http": "staticxx.facebook.com",
  "cdn_https": "staticxx.facebook.com"
});
```

I cannot reproduce this config mapping deterministically. Sometimes the `api_` endpoints use `z-m-*` and sometimes they do not.

---

**UPDATE** (2017-10-17T15:36+00:00)

re: Why do I care that the SDK is attempting to access a different Graph API host than expected?

I use the SDK to make Graph API calls as part of a registration / login experience. Due to the secure nature of this page I follow [OWASP guidelines](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Content_Security_Policy) and [implement a strict Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://content-security-policy.com/).

Following the [security principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege), the CSP only allows connections to and assets from hosts I expect the application to require. As `z-m-graph.facebook.com` is [not documented or referenced anywhere](https://developers.facebook.com/search/?q=z-m-graph.facebook.com) and `graph.facebook.com` is used specifically and exclusively in all examples and instructions, `graph.facebook.com` is permitted while `z-m-graph.facebook.com` is not.

---

I'd love help chasing down answers / leads to the following:

1. How can I force the SDK to always use `graph.facebook.com`?
2. What is `z-m-graph.facebook.com`?
3. Where can I find documentation for `z-m-graph.facebook.com`?
4. Are there other hosts that the JS SDK may attempt to use for Graph API requests? What are they?

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: 1. why, 2. prob'ly nonna ya beeswax (might be part of their load balancing, A/B testing, countless other things), 3. why should that even be documented (especially considering 2.), 4. again why would you need to know in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've noticed there's

1. graph.facebook.com
2. z-m-graph.facebook.com and
3. b-graph.facebook.com

Z.M should mean zero mode which is used in countries where network providers enable you to use Facebook free with a capped data and no viewable media (most of the times) Facebook made this mode for mass adoption in developing countries. Note: free.facebook.com does not use z-m-graph.facebook.com but pure HTML doc since it's freebasics program specifies only HTML and no JavaScript for very limited phones

B should mean basic I don't know much about it but seems to have some similarities with the above or used in slow or limited connections ( not  so sure)

What I've noticed with messing around with the Whitehat settings on Facebook app is they all end up at the same end point on the server (95% sure) have the same body parameters in the post and most importantly if assuming your ISP supports it if you toggle between free mode the app switch to z-m (zero mode) and sometimes b (basic) if photos don't show up or maybe network is slowed and finally graph.facebook.com when you toggle back to data mode so z-m-graph.facebook.com has no docs because very few Devs would need it since it is very ISP dependent in Nigeria out of the top three major ISP's only two support Facebook z-m graph point so I can't use z-m graph point on the other network so it doesn't make sense to write docs for it but it has similarities to the other hope this is good for you ; )

Comment: This looks like a pretty good answer and I'm minded to up-vote it, but do you have any links to the things you are talking about?